# TypeScript conditional types for props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a component that can be in two different states, editing mode and viewing mode. To accommodate for that I have a union type to make this work, but I still get TypeScript complaining in the args of my component:

```js
type View = {
    isEditing: false;
    viewHandler: () => void;
    someOtherProp: any // this is unique to view mode
};

type Edit = {
    isEditing: true;
    editHandler: (id: string) => void;
};

export type MyProps = View | Edit;
```

It is then complaining here:

```
const Item: React.FC<MyProps> = ({
    isEditing = false,
    editHandler,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~
}) => {
```

`Property 'editHandler' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<MyProps>'.`

What am I missing?

Comment: So, if  `isEditing` is `false` you want it to be `View`, if  `isEditing`  is not provided, or `true` it is `Edit`, at the same time if  `isEditing`  is not provided ( `Edit` mode) you default it to `false` (`View` mode). Can you provide examples of how you plan to use thiscomponent?

Comment: In Edit mode it should really not be optional, that was an oversight, so the component is either in Edit or in View mode, depending on which mode it is in, we render different child components that we pass the handlers into. We are passing the handlers all the way down the tree, to manage our state on a page level and keep the logic in one place.

Comment: Maybe `type View = { isEditing?: false;editHandler: undefined};` and `type Edit = {isEditing: true;editHandler: (id: string) => void;};`  will work for you? Or better still make 2 components

Comment: No, tried this already, then I get `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` at the point where I invoke the handler

Comment: Using `!` makes TS know something is not null /undefined `editHandler!()`

Comment: Yes, that actually does work! I now typed it as `never` wherever it is not used and used the `!` to tell TS that it'll not be undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the solution I used now is adding it and typing it as `never`:

```js
type View = {
    isEditing: false;
    viewHandler: () => void;
    editHandler?: never;
};

type Edit = {
    isEditing: true;
    editHandler: (id: string) => void;
    viewHandler?: never;
};

export type MyProps = View | Edit;
```

And at the point where the event handler gets invoked or passed down, I use a `!` to assure TypeScript that this cannot be undefined.
Kudos to Nadia who pointed me in the right direction in a comment above!

Answer (score 2):

I think it should also be present in your View type like this:

```
type View = {
  isEditing: false;
  editHandler?:(id: string) => void;
};

type Edit = {
  isEditing?: true;
  editHandler: (id: string) => void;
};
```

Comment: This is a very simplified dummy code, there are multiple handlers and other props that are passed, so adding all handlers in both cases is adding a lot of redundancy and isn't very type safe, that would mean the ViewMode would still be able to get the Edit handlers passed and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah i understand that...but as you have written `export type MyProps = View | Edit` then View and Edit should have the keys that you want to have in `React.FC<MyProps> = ({ isEditing = false, editHandler })`.

Comment: Just been trying this approach to see if that works, and now I actually get `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` where I invoke the function

Comment: Marking the `isEditing` property optional is a good choice. One less property to pass to the React component. If it isn't passed, it will default to false which means `View` type is considered.

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface ViewProps {
  isEditing?: false;
  viewHandler: () => void;
  someOtherProp: any;
}

interface EditProps {
  isEditing: true;
  editHandler: (id: string) => void;
  viewHandler?: never;
}

const Item = (props: ViewProps | EditProps) => {
  if (props.isEditing) {
    return <EditItem {...props} />;
  }
  return <ViewItem {...props} />;
};

const ViewItem = (props: ViewProps) => <div>View</div>;

const EditItem = (props: EditProps) => <div>Edit</div>;
```

Usage:

```js
<Item viewHandler={() => {}} someOtherProp="" />;
<Item isEditing editHandler={() => {}} />;
```

All other combinations are not allowed.